# How to install all Windows 8 partitions on single drive on multidrive system?

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, multi-boot, windows-installation

Yesterday I wiped Windows and Linux systems and reinstalled them. My disk setup is:

```
sda - ext4 - 2TB HDD - data
sdb - ext4 - 2TB HDD - data
sdc - NTFS - 3TB HDD - backup
sdd - NTFS - 120GB SSD - Windows 8
sde - ext4 - 512GB SSD - Linux
```

I moved my data to sdc and wiped clean sd{a,b,d,e} and reformatted.
Then I installed Windows 8 on sdd and then Ubuntu 15.10 on sde.

To my surprise I found that partitions looks now like this:

```
$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT                        LABEL
sda    btrfs    1,8T                                   
├─sda1 ntfs     350M                                   Zastrzeżone przez system
├─sda2 btrfs      1K                                   
└─sda5 ext4     1,8T                                   
sdb    ext4     1,8T                                   
sdc             2,7T                                   
├─sdc1          128M                                   
├─sdc2 vfat     100M /boot/efi                         
└─sdc3 ntfs     2,7T /media/sebastian/AE3A52803A52460D 
sdd           111,8G                                   
└─sdd1 ntfs   111,8G                                   
sde             477G                                   
└─sde1 ext4     477G /
```

Not to mention that GRUB shows weird entry for windows "Windows Boot Manager" and want to repair itself when this is selected.

Why did the Windows installer scatter its normal recovery/efi/data partitions across sda, sdc and sdd instead of installing everything on sdd as I wanted? How to install entire Windows on a single disk?

This weird 1K brtfs partition bothers me a little bit. There was btrfs partition before on this disk, but I formatted it to ext4 with the Linux installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this problem. My steps was:

- physically reorder hard drives on mainboard so 120GB disk I wanted to host Windows was first one ("Disk 0" in Windows nomenclature and "sda" in Linux nomenclature)
- started Windows installer, selected advanced partitioning options
- removed all bootloader, efi, recovery partitions Windows created previously
- remove partitions from Disk 0
- selected Disk 0 as place to install Windows and continued installation without problems

Then I installed Linux, installed GRUB on sdb (512GB Linux partition) so it won't touch Windows disk and configured UEFI to boot up from sdb and everything works as I wanted.